# php changeint up to certain point

Tags: php, mysql

So i am creating some sort of access/level system very basic i am new to this thing. I created 2 buttons one for lowering value by 1 and one for ascending value but i want to limit values to be between 0 and 3 at current state i can go up to -9 and 9 because in my sql i set it up to contain only 2 characters. So how would i so that my current code for ascending value looks like this.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
include 'connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['sl'])) {
$id = $_GET['sl'];
$sqld = "UPDATE acc SET lvl = lvl+1 WHERE username = '$id'";
$res = mysql_query($sqld);
header('location: korisnici.php');
}
?>
```

So i though about pulling lvl value from table before changing it and saying if lvl is higher than 3 or lower than 0 dont do anything but for some reason its not working maybe i did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE acc SET lvl = IF(lvl < 3, lvl + 1, 3) WHERE username = N
```